# uncompress zlib network packet from hex

Tags: php, networking, reverse, zlib, compression

I am reversing some kind of protocol and it looks like it is using zlib compression, the current packet is :

```
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
```

If we take a look at rfc1950 we see the specifications of the format, in my script (php) i extract the zlib related info for the above packet :

```
compression method : 1
compression info   : 7
------------------------------
flag check          : 0
flag dict           : 0
flag level          : 3
```

However I cannot find a way to uncompress the hex data, even if I convert it to a binary string with `pack('H*',$data)` it still gives an error about wrong data.

Is it possible to use a commandline program and feed it with the above hex data where the commandline utility returns the uncompressed string in HEX.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a python script for decompressing zlib streams:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130305133247/http://blog.2of1.org/2011/03/03/decompressing-zlib-images/

.. but your data is not zlib compressed.

Cursory look shows that your data is cleanly divided by a 4 byte marker "17 03 00 00" followed by a length byte indicating size of that segment.

```
17 03 00 00 20 09 25 4C BC E1 DC 7A 55 78 D1 58
85 77 EF 63 AE 8D DC A7 21 FF CA 45 37 75 BC A7
37 5C B6 5E E3 

               17 03 00 00 90 AA 88 3A 35 5C B9
A7 45 0E A7 BA 8D 48 5C 65 5E B5 FC B7 1E 22 F2
74 E9 FF 03 F3 26 29 6E 7F 2D 59 60 AB 7C FB 29
86 C4 98 5D 6B 7D 33 BE 2C 73 48 14 2D 73 8B 52
2C 3B 89 AA 37 23 A5 CA DB 9C 3D F1 24 B3 AB 40
5E 05 13 76 63 84 D3 C0 C6 C1 13 95 D5 1E 31 7F
1D F3 42 F3 73 1D 49 8C 84 EE 0B E9 17 2C 13 0A
89 C7 EE 28 75 60 E6 43 37 E4 A0 D4 9A 21 1E 40
F8 46 DB AF 01 9A DE F2 F2 F6 01 A1 45 C1 F5 87
C7 92 CF 3C 2E E1 CE E5 58 03 

                              17 03 00 00 20 25
9B AF BA DA BE 5B 22 36 0C 72 7D 6E 24 94 C4 15
42 FC 3E 14 EE E3 B5 31 7C 13 F0 60 44 BB 77 

                                             17
03 00 00 50 12 E5 BF 7E 63 1E 9E 3C 5F 0D 13 38
90 80 82 81 A7 69 C3 AE C5 0A CF 8B B0 FB F3 9C
AE C0 E2 EA 75 C0 9B AD 7A 3F 22 A1 5D C2 B5 C3
75 15 61 DB 32 19 16 4A B8 0E 55 A7 DB 14 1F 5F
6F AB 4D E9 18 9C C1 45 C4 7E 49 D7 41 07 5D DA
A6 EF D2 A6
```

So lengths here are:

```
0x20 in first case
0x90 in second segment
0x20 in 3rd segment
0x50 in 4th segment.
```

And this corresponds correctly with marker positions.

I could spend a while to reverse this, but I think this should be enough to bring you back to correct path.

Hope this helps.